# jquery .load() in .load() flickers. Why?

Tags: jquery, function

I'm usind this function to navigate inside a .load() content. The first two or three click-throughs are working but then I get a strange flickering between the .loaded subcontents.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){

    $("ul.sub li a").live('click', function (e)
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".textbox").load($(this).attr("href") +  " .subcontent");
    });
});
```

Anybody know why?

**SOLUTION:**

```
$(function(){
  $("ul.linkbox li a").live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    $(".textbox").load($(this).attr("href") +  " .subcontent");
   });
});
```

Thanks @karim79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say, but probably because you are adding a new click handler every time an ajax request completes?

Comment: I found this function in the internet. Is there a way o rewrite it safely?

Comment: @Melros - just remove the outer `$(document).ajaxcomplete` so your code is just `$("ul.sub li a").live('click', function (e)
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".textbox").load($(this).attr("href") +  " .subcontent");
    });`